# Fill out video file attributes

Tags: windows, video, attributes, metadata, avi

I have a large collection of video files, which have missing atributes like length, resolution, bitrate etc. I would like to fill those out somehow but im not sure what solution to use. It would take ages by hand but i'd rather see if a program can do it first. I tried searching for a solution but didnt find anything substantial.

The reason why, is becuase im trying to filter out the videos by atributes. If a vid is shorter than 30 minutes, i delete it. Can sort with the windows explorer, which cant do that if the atributes are missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you asked this on StackOverflow and not on SuperUser I'm going to answer this as a programming question.

Those properties are provided by the [Windows Property System](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff728898(v=vs.85).aspx). It is possible to write your own property provider and overwrite the system default provider registration but this is a fair amount of work if all you want to do is sort some files.